# Fileupload not working with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: python, c++, qt, swagger

I have a swagger generated (python-flask) web-server, which supports a variety of requests, which are fed by requests sent from an instance of QNetworkAccessManager (GET, PUT, POST).
They actually work like a charm, so I assume, that I got the main usage right, more or less.

What doesn't work though, is file upload using POST request. I actually tried several variants:

- Providing the file content with QNetworkAccessManager::send,
- Providing the file-pointer with QNetworkAccessManager::send (yes, I made sure, that the file is open and valid during the complete operation and cleaned up afterwards),
- Using QMultiPart (see example below),
- Playing with the request parameters didn't help either

But whatever I try, the request is recorded in the web-server, but `connexion.request.files.getlist('file')` is empty.

On the other hand, using `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' -F "file=@/path/to/file/image.jpg" {"type":"formData"} '$myURL'` makes it `[<FileStorage: 'image.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>]`.

```
  void uploadImage(QUrl const& url, std::filesystem::path const& filepath)
  {
    QNetworkRequest request {url};
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
    QHttpPart imagePart;
    imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"" + QString::fromStdString(filepath.filename().native()) + "\"; filename=\"" + QString::fromStdString(filepath.native()) + "\""));
    imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/jpeg"));

    QFile *file = new QFile(QString::fromStdString(filepath.native()));
    if (!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        std::cout << "could not open file" << std::endl;
    }
    QByteArray fileContent(file->readAll());
    imagePart.setBody(fileContent);
    multiPart->append(imagePart);

    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, file->size());
    auto reply = _manager->post(request, multiPart);
    file->setParent(reply);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, reply, &QNetworkReply::deleteLater);
  }
```

QProcess using the curl command wasn't that happy and me neither, because, even though I'm running the code currently on a Linux machine, I don't want to restrict to Linux only.

Are there any suggestions on how to use Qt-Network in this context?